# Difference between this and that as a demonstrated adjective

Tags: difference

Two people talking about a man which is not present at that moment. One of them said how will you find this man?
Why did the people use this instead of that?

Answer (score 1):

The use of both **that** and **this** is correct.
They used "*this*" because they were currently talking about the man, and hence, they were pointing to "this man they were talking about".

Comment: The fact that they were *pointing* at the man (that's not stated in the question—and, in fact, isn't possible because the question says that the man isn't present, unless you mean it figuratively) doesn't, itself, determine if it should be **this** or **that**. If you point at something in the distance, you use **that**; if you point at something next to you, you use **this**. It's not the pointing that determines the word, it's the distance between yourself and the object. (Either literally or figuratively.)

Comment: @JasonBassford I used **pointing** metaphorically, not literally.